# how can send ERC-20 Token to multiple address in solidity from deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, airdrop

Here is my mulsend contract code and Here I want to send token to multiple address from another deployed contract this is my deployed contract:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x8fd22db75d8bc9a95c08bb4907f45e411a7b6251

**Advance Thanks.**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.4.0/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.4.0/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";
contract BatchSendERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    
    address public owner;
    
    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    
    constructor() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
   
    //getowner
    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }
    
    //get token balance
    function getTokenBalance(IERC20 token) public view returns (uint256) {
        return token.balanceOf(address(this));
    }
    
    //batch send different token amount from contract
    function multiSendDiffTokenFromContract(IERC20 token, address[] memory recipients, uint256[] memory amounts) public onlyOwner {
        
        require(recipients.length > 0);
        require(recipients.length == amounts.length);
        
        uint256 length = recipients.length;
        uint256 currentSum = 0;
        uint256 currentTokenBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            uint256 amount = amounts[i];
            require(amount > 0);
            currentSum = currentSum.add(amount);
            require(currentSum <= currentTokenBalance);
            
            token.safeTransfer(recipients[i], amount);
        }
    }
    
}
```

When i call multiSendDiffTokenFromContract after deploy contract and  give function parameter value  showing this error message "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted".

Comment: Do you have enough tokens that you are trying to send on your BatchSendERC20 contract?

Comment: No,,But i have on this https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x8fd22db75d8bc9a95c08bb4907f45e411a7b6251
contract ,How can i send token from this contract using BatchSendERC20 contract,,,Is it possible???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i codied your code it works fine in locally on remix environment, are trying to deploy then calling it ??, please send screenshot of error will really help

Comment: yes, this code is work fine. but my problem is, i want to send token to multiple address from this https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x8fd22db75d8bc9a95c08bb4907f45e411a7b6251  contract, that's why i am developed BatchSendERC20 contract that interact with other contract and send token from  https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x8fd22db75d8bc9a95c08bb4907f45e411a7b6251  contract ....How can i do that??,,,is there any way to do multisend token without using 3rd party app...Thanks for reply @Derek

Comment: idk what is going wrong with you but i tried deploying it and it work fine look  [link](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xe828695be936428db78c19c92e9cc11227573c647a3985e3adee5ac318061c40)

Comment: do you have enough funds, in your `multitrasnfer`contract address

Comment: no ...multisender  contract address have not anough fund..how can i get fund

Comment: transfer some token from other address or mint some tokens from the same address of erc20 contract

Comment: sorry ,I think I can't explain my issue perfectly. for example 
I have erc20 smart contract on testnet/mainnet ,i am a owner o this contract . now  i want  send token to multiple token to multiple address from my contract in a transaction.
now I develop a different contract that help to send token to multiple  address from my erc20 smart contract.
I think you understand my issue.

Comment: i got your issue, let me explain as you have created the second contract you must have balance to send from from you contract to others address, u got me ???

Comment: look at this link https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xe828695be936428db78c19c92e9cc11227573c647a3985e3adee5ac318061c40

Comment: Thanks @Derek....Now i am understand

Answer (score 0):

You must calculate has enough token in your contract and then send tokens to recipients, therefor I added totalSend function for this, please check this contract.

```
contract BatchSendERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner(){
       require(msg.sender == owner);
       _;
    }

    constructor() public{
       owner = msg.sender;
    }

    //getowner
    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }

    //get token balance
    function getTokenBalance(IERC20 token) public view returns (uint256) {
        return token.balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function totalSend(uint256[] memory amounts) internal pure returns(uint256) {
          uint256 length = amounts.lebngth;
          uint256 totalAmount;
      for(uint256 i=0; i < length; i++) {
        totalAmount += amounts[i];
      }
      return totalAmount
    }
    //batch send different token amount from contract
    function multiSendDiffTokenFromContract(IERC20 token, address[]     memory recipients, uint256[] memory amounts) public onlyOwner {
    
        require(recipients.length > 0);
        require(recipients.length == amounts.length);
    
        uint256 length = recipients.length;
        uint256 totalToSend = totalSend(amounts);
        uint256 currentTokenBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(currentTokenBalance >= totalToSend)
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            uint256 amount = amounts[i];
            require(amount > 0);
            token.safeTransfer(recipients[i], amount);
        }
    }

}
```